# How do i display a select stored procedure result in a textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need to display the result from a select statement in a stored procedure onto the textbox and I can't figure out how to do it. The select statement doesn't use a WHERE clause. The stored procedure goes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewCustomer
AS
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM Database
END
```

This is what I've tried

```js
protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
        int num;

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("NewCustomer"))
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.TryParse(txtCID.Text, out num); // Use tryparse if needed
                conn.Open();
                txtCID.Text = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        }
```

It gives me a "Procedure NewCID has no parameters and arguments were supplied." Error

Comment: Is that a sample procedure to show your scenario or really you are using it as a procedure?

Comment: At what line does the error appear? I'm guessing the problem is that you're assigning `txtCID.Text` to the `Value` property of a parameter of type `SqlDbType.Int`.

Comment: @Prdp I was using it as an example, but I have edited it to show what i'm actually using.

Comment: @OnkelToob so would I just have to convert the txtCID to Int32?

Comment: @Anon Yes, that would at least be my first guess. But I see you've edited your question, so the problem seems to have shifted to something else...

Comment: @OnkelToob Don't worry. Solved it all haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the procedure that you ware given. The procedure is named as `yadayada`(*The worst name that you can give*) and you are executing the procedure  `NewCustomer` as the command text. Both has to be same. Then you are using the Wrong statement for executing the query.

> The [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform catalog operations (for example,
>   querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such
>   as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a
>   DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

But you are using it for executing the select query. Here you are selecting a single value from the table so the ExecuteScalar will be the best option for you. Your code will be like this: assume the procedure name is `GetNewCustomerID`;

```
 using (SqlCommand exeCommand = new SqlCommand("GetNewCustomerID"))
 {
     exeCommand.Connection = conn;
     exeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     exeCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustID",SqlDbType.Int).Value=Convert.ToInt32(txtCID.Text); // Use tryparse if needed
     conn.Open();
     txtCID.Text = (string)exeCommand.ExecuteScalar(); 
 }
```

Comment: I was just using yadayada as an example

Comment: I've updated the example to something like yours but now I get a different error.